# finding $du/dx$ if $u=u(x)$ is defined with system of equations

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Assume function $u=u(x)$ is defined with that system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
u=f(x,y,z)\\
g(x,y,z)=0\\
h(x,y,z)=0
\end{cases}
$$
How can i find $du/dx$?

Please help, i don't know how to start solving this..

Comment: You take the expression of $f$ and calculate the derivative as if $y$ and $z$ were constants.

Comment: For what's seen, and if not more info is given: $$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by using the chain rule.
\begin{equation}
u(x) = f(x,y(x),z(x))
\end{equation}
so
\begin{align*}
u'(x) &= \frac{\partial f(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial x}
+ \frac{\partial f(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial y} y'(x)
+ \frac{\partial f(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial z} z'(x).
\end{align*}

Implicit differentiation allows us to find formulas for $y'(x)$ and $z'(x)$.
\begin{equation}
g(x,y(x),z(x)) = 0
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial x}
+ \frac{\partial g(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial y}y'(x)
+ \frac{\partial g(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial z}z'(x) = 0
\end{equation}
and similarly
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial h(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial x}
+ \frac{\partial h(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial y}y'(x)
+ \frac{\partial h(x,y(x),z(x))}{\partial z}z'(x) = 0.
\end{equation}

These equations can be used to solve for $y'(x)$ and $z'(x)$.